# Combined multiple Indicator Columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns representing categorical variables and the data in the columns is either 1 or 0 as an indicator like below:

```
    ID   A  B  C  D
    100  1  0  0  0
    101  0  0  1  0
    102  0  1  0  0
    103  0  0  0  1
```

I would like to represent this information as one column of data such as:

```
    ID    VALUE
    100   A
    101   C
    102   B
    103   D
```

Is there a method in python to acheive this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stack()` is a command that comes often handy:

```
df2 = df.set_index('ID').stack().reset_index()
df2[df2[0] == 1][['ID', 'level_1']]

Out[370]: 
     ID level_1
0   100       A
6   101       C
9   102       B
15  103       D
```

This is just the rough steps, getting the output nicely formatted is left as an exercise for the interested reader.